# API SQL foreign key reference validation

Tags: sql, node.js, api

I'm developing an API on node at the moment and have a model that has a lot of foreign key references (15+) to other models.

I'd like to at least validate that the incoming `POST` payload contains IDs that exist in the other tables, but I'm not sure where to validate this.

If I simply try to insert it into the database, there'll be a SQL foreign key constraint error. I could capture this and attempt to relay the information to the API response.

Should I be doing each validation individually *before* I try the insert?

Comment: @tadman I'm guessing the insert wouldn't fail often, but it'd be great to be able to give a useful response rather than the raw SQL error message. Thanks, I think I'll go with the optimistic approach for now then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you. How often are these likely to fail? Optimistic approach is jam it in and hope for the best. Pessimistic is to systematically check each relationship beforehand.

You can always re-word the error to make it more palatable. It's typically the case you can have a closer look at the error to try and figure out what relationship failed, then come up with a custom error that explains in terms someone will understand.

Normally I do this by having a mapping table from table name to the label used to describe that table. In most applications foreign keys don't just fizzle out randomly, that requires interaction from a user.

Maybe during the process of submitting the form something expired, someone deleted something, or some other event occurred. These happen, but far less often than successful submissions.